# anidar tablas con puro sql

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, mariadb

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado de todo pero de que forma puedo hacer algo parecido en `heidy sql` con server `mariaDB`.

Necesito anidar 3 tablas así como en ese ejemplo de la imagen.

He intentado algo así:

```
SELECT * 
FROM venta
WHERE folio = '2022042289043'
UNION
SELECT *
FROM detalles
WHERE folio = '2022042289043'
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM productos
WHERE sku = 5
;
```

Pero dice que es ambiguo y no me funciona. Alguna sugerencia o alguna manera de hacer el ejemplo de la imagen pero con código `sql`?

Comment: Cuando hay preguntas de base de datos, es muy útil colocar los scripts de creación de las tablas y algunos datos de referencia (cuidado con que se te pasen los datos de empresa, podría haber problemas legales por ello), con esto, se hace más fácil que la comunidad pueda reproducir tu escenario y por consiguiente, se elevan las chances de obtener una respuesta. Aquí una lista de recomendaciones de lo que incluir en las preguntas en SOes: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Cuando haces un UNION, estás generando la unión de los resultados de cada select. Eso funciona si cada select retorna **los mismos campos**. Supongo que cada tabla tiene campos diferentes, así que no debería funcionar. Por favor, sigue la recomendación que te hacen, ve a [edit] y añade las definiciones de las tablas, la salida esperada y el mensaje de error completo (no resumas los errores).

Comment: Siento decirte que eso que queres, no se puede hacer con sql.. Eso, no es la salida standard de ningun query sql, porque las salidas son filas. Eso es un json, y deberias construir un json (algunas db tienen como hacerlo, por ejemplo oracle). Pero no es un query.